# TLS 1.3 : Base Key Meaning

Tags: encryption, tls

What is significance of following Base Key in **TLS1.3** draft (28).

1. **server_handshake_traffic_secret**
2. **client_handshake_traffic_secret**
3. **client_application_traffic_secret_N**

So far I understand

1. **server_handshake_traffic_secret** should be private key using which certificate has been acquired.
2. **client_handshake_traffic_secret ??**
3. **client_application_traffic_secret_N**  should be symmetric keys established after the handshake where N denotes number of up-gradation in keys after handshake.

Please suggest correction and explanation for client_handshake_traffic_secret . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See sections 7.2 and 7.3 of the draft.

Each secret is used by a specific endpoint (client or server) at a specific moment of the exchange: so first the handshake secrets are used then the application ones, and keys are derived from the secrets.

So the `server_handshake_traffic_secret` is what the server side uses to exchange data during the handshake and `client_handshake_traffic_secret` is the exact equivalent from the client part.